# How can I access another function inside the react Context.Provider value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

At the moment, I learn how to use react context API. 
I have a react Provider class, with some state data and functions in the `value={}`. How can I access a function inside this value from another function inside this value?

So, the `function1()` is called by a child component. When the state change is finished, I want to call the `function2()` and access the new state.

Is it possible in react to get something like this?:

```js
class Provider extends Component {
  state = {
    foo: 'bar'
  }

  render() {
    return() {
      <Context.Provider value={{
        state: this.state,

        function1: () => {
          this.setState({ foo: 'changed' }, () => {
            // HERE I WANT TO CALL THE NEXT FUNCTION IN THIS VALUE
            this.function2()
          });
        },

        function2: () => {
          // called by function1 after state change
          console.log(this.state)
        }
      }}>
        { this.props.children }
      </Context.Provider>
    }
  }
}
```

If I try to run this, and fire the `function1()` from the child, it gives me

**`TypeError: _this2.function2() is not a function`**

I don't understand, why it is trying to access a `_this2` variable, because I defined it to access `this.function2()`.

Is it just not possible to do what I want in react? You might say, why the `function2()` is an extra function, and why I don't add the code in the end of the `function1()`. It's because the `function2()` has to be a independent accessable function.

Can anyone help me? Thanks!

Comment: change both arrow function `function1: () =>` to normal function `function function1 () {`

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar This is not possible, because the functions are in an object.

Comment: this way: `function1: function() {}`

Comment: @naga-elixir-jar then I get **Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can try to do is this:-

```
class Provider extends Component {
    state = {
    foo: 'bar'
  }

  an_independent_function() {
    console.log(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return() {
      <Context.Provider value={{
        state: this.state,

        function1: () => {
          this.setState({ foo: 'changed' }, () => {
            // HERE I WANT TO CALL THE NEXT FUNCTION IN THIS VALUE
            this.an_independent_function();
          });
        },

        function2: this.an_independent_function.bind(this)
      }}>
        { this.props.children }
      </Context.Provider>
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much! That workes perfectly :) ! Even though VS Code's syntax highlighting is going bit crazy now, but it works.